# AAD B2C IEF: How to pass error code and message from REST API to the application with costom policy?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using custom policy to invoke a REST API to get something from database and return in claims. It works fine but I need to extend the feature to send extra error code and error message in case any exception happens. I already returned such information as requested ("status":409, "userMessage":). But I don't know where I can get it (in HTTP header/body/somewhere else?). I understand that I can return such information in another claim. But since AAD B2C provides the status code and userMessage there must be a way to use it. Could someone please enlighten me? Thanks a lot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU3gq.png)

Comment: try and format your question better. the image is not visible and the error code can be better displayed.

Comment: Can you be more specific, the wording of your question is unclear.
Do you want to access the REST response error message text in your policy flow?

Answer (score 0):

The error message itself can’t be accessed as a claim. If you want processing to continue, then return a HTTP 200 with a JSON representing the error and use preconditions to control the journey in this case.